# How to replace Object.entries for ie?

Tags: javascript

I develop this little script :

```
const filteredAttributes = Object.entries(meta.attributes)
  .filter(([_, value]) => !!value)
  .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => ({ ...acc, [key]: value }), {})
```

This script remove all keys have a falsy value into an object.

Unfortunately this script is not working on ie11, the config of my project use babel to create a valid output for ie.
But I haven't **polyfill** for `Object.entries` and **I can't add one**.

How I can replace `Object.entries` with a compatible ie11 code ?

Comment: ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#Polyfill Just searching for your question title would have been a lot quicker.

Comment: @DaveNewton "But I haven't polyfill for Object.entries and I can't add one." Read the question

Comment: ... The code in the polyfill is equivalent code. Whether you use it as a polyfill or standalone is irrelevant--that's how you replace it, whether it's added to `Object` or whether its run on its own. I *did* read the question--maybe you should take a step back and think a little bit.

Comment: @DaveNewton Sure "think a little bit", that's great. I'll remember it next time, "Just searching" & "think a little bit". An answer for all questions, you are the best thank a lot.

Comment: Notice the polyfill code's direct relationship to Nina's answer. `Object.entries` is keys + values: get the keys via `Object.keys`, get the value with the key. You focused on the word "polyfill", perhaps not recognizing that polyfills are just equivalent code attached to an object. If you don't attach it, it's still the same code, it's just not a polyfill. Your question title leads directly to the code you wanted--you saw only how the code was *used*, missing the forest for the trees. Unrelated: you're choosing to make this a fight; I am not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

You need to replace destructuring parts as well.

```
var filteredAttributes = Object
        .keys(meta.attributes)
        .filter(function (key) { return meta.attributes[key]; })
        .reduce(function (acc, key) {
            acc[key] = meta.attributes[key];
            return acc;
        }, {});
```